# Catching runtime error for process created by python subprocess

Tags: python, c, error-handling, signals, subprocess

I am writing a script which can take a file name as input, compile it and run it.

I am taking the name of a file as input(input_file_name). I first compile the file from within python:

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(['gcc', input_file_name, '-o', 'auto_gen'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

Next, I'm executing the executable using the same(Popen) call:

```
subprocess.Popen('./auto_gen', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=False)
```

In both cases, I'm catching the stdout(and stderr) contents using

```
(output, _) = self.process.communicate()
```

Now, if there is an error during compilation, I am able to catch the error because the returncode is 1 and I can get the details of the error because gcc sends them on stderr.

However, the program itself can return a random value even on executing successfully(because there might not be a "return 0" at the end). So I can't catch runtime errors using the returncode. Moreover, the executable does not send the error details on stderr. So I can't use the trick I used for catching compile-time errors.

What is the best way to catch a runtime error OR to print the details of the error? That is, if ./auto_gen throws a segmentation fault, I should be able to print either one of:

```
'Runtime error'
'Segmentation Fault'
'Program threw a SIGSEGV'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  The code runs a subprocess which fails and prints to stderr.  The `except` block captures the specific error exit code and stdout/stderr, and displays it.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(
        "ls non_existent_file",
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        shell=True)
    print 'okay:',out
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print 'error: code={}, out="{}"'.format(
        exc.returncode, exc.output,
        )
```

Example output:

```
$ python ./subproc.py 
error: code=2, out="ls: cannot access non_existent_file: No such file or directory
"
```

Comment: OP said that the child process may return *arbitrary* exit status because there is no `return 0` (try to build and run `main() {}` C program) i.e., you can't use `returncode != 0` to detect failure. Child process also doesn't print errors to stderr (and stdout it seems) therefore `exc.output` also doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If `./autogen` is killed by a signal then `self.process.returncode` (after `.wait()` or `.communicate()`) is less than zero and its absolute value reports the signal e.g., `returncode == -11` for `SIGSERV`.

Answer (score -1):

please check following link for runtime errors or output of subprocess

https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python

```
def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print output.strip()
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc
```

Comment: Note that the article mentioned, "Getting realtime output using Python Subprocess", has moved to: https://www.endpointdev.com/blog/2015/01/getting-realtime-output-using-python/